# css background on every element

Tags: css

I have a bunch of different elements on my page and I want to apply a tiled background to everything. If I try to do it to the body section, only some chunks get the background. What's an easy way to do this? I'm already using jQuery, so if there's a solution that involves that, I'm open to it.

Comment: [`* { background: yada yada }`](http://jsfiddle.net/Vu7BC/) would do it, but that sounds like a terrible idea...

Comment: What do you mean by "only some chunks"?

Comment: Sounds like some of your elements already have a background set.  Otherwise a body{background: ...}  would show through all elements, since they are transparent by default.

Comment: Taking @Vigrond's comment into consideration, an [`!important`](http://jsfiddle.net/Vu7BC/1/) should override the `background`s. But really, you should find another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
* {background: blue;}
```

Or whatever it is you want the background to be.

That said, what do you mean by "only some chunks get it"? Surely:

```
html {background: blue;}
```

should be enough?

Comment: Only certain chunks were working because there was a stray background-repeat:repeat-y; in there. Didn't know about * selector, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine that you could assign the `background-image` to the `body` element, and then assign a transparent `background-color` to the descendent elements:

```
body {
    background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
}

body * {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

It's worth noting, though, that most elements (from personal experience) tend to be `transparent` by *default*, so it's entirely probably that you're assigning an alternate background to those elements that don't 'get' it.